# How can I sort a request to a view - using nodejs API

Tags: sorting, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I'm querying a cloudant DB from my nodejs App.
I am now trying to sort results from a view query. 
My index (keys) are like this:
[ "FR000001", 1577189089166 ]
[ "FR000001", 1577189089165 ]
etc

from the following view:

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.siteId, doc.creationDate],{"id" :doc._id, "rev": doc._rev, "siteId": doc.siteId, "creationDate": doc.creationDate, "scores": doc.scores, locationId: doc.locationId});
}
```

I managed to make that work on a real index using the syntax "sort: "-creationDate" " using syntax found in the bugs sections of cloudant github.

```
var ddoc = {
    q: "site:\"" + id + "\"",
    include_docs: false,
    sort: "-creationDate",
  };
  const tmp = await cloudant.use('alarms').search('alarmSearch', 'IndexBySite', ddoc);
```

I can't make it work on my view with an array of query parameters. I have tried different variation around:

```
var ddoc_view = {
    startkey: ["siteid1",0000000000000],
    endkey: ["siteid1",9999999999999],
    include_docs: true,
    sort: "creationDate" 
  };
```

Can anyone help finding the right syntax, or pointing me to where I can find good "cloudant API for nodejs" documentation? for instance there is nothing on how to use sort" on the github... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

ok after another day of searching:
- best documentation I found is directly the couchdb doc: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html
- I ended up modifying the view:

```
emit([doc.creationDate, doc.siteId], {"id" :doc._id, "rev": doc._rev, "siteId": doc.siteId, "locationTag":doc.locationTag});
```

and the request:

```
  var ddoc_view = {
    endkey: [0000000000000, siteid],
    startkey: [9999999999999, siteid],
    include_docs: false,
    descending: true,
    limit: docsReturned,
  };
```

To get a sorted response.